# how can I use recursive concept with a relational class?

Tags: c#

I have three table (School - Class - Student) and I make model like the following

```
class School
{
    private int _School_ID;  // School Primary Key
    public int School_ID 
    { get { return _School_ID; } set { _School_ID = value; } }

    public string _School_Name;
    private string School_Name 
    { get { return _School_Name; } set { _School_Name = value; } }
}

class Class
{
    private int _Class_ID;  // Class Primary Key
    public int Class_ID 
    { get { return _Class_ID; } set { _Class_ID = value; } }

    public string _Class_Name;
    private string Class_Name 
    { get { return _Class_Name; } set { _Class_Name = value; } }

    private int _School_ID;  // School Foreign Key
    public int School_ID 
    { get { return _School_ID; } set { _School_ID = value; } }
}

class Student
{
    private int _Student_ID;  // Student Primary Key
    public int Student_ID 
    { get { return _Student_ID; } set { _Student_ID = value; } }

    public string _Student_Name;
    private string Student_Name 
    { get { return _Student_Name; } set { _Student_Name = value; } }

    private int _Class_ID;  // Class Foreign Key
    public int Class_ID 
    { get { return _Class_ID; } set { _Class_ID = value; } }
}
```

The Question is:

- How can I make a relational class by using foreign key if it possible ?
- How can I use recursive concept to get id from upper class by knowing id of lower class like the following

====================== 
1 - Puts Student id 
2 - Student(1).Class.School 
3 - return School id

Comment: Side note: this concept more commonly referred as "parent/child" or "contains" rather than "recursive". Following would indeed be "recursive" data structures - linked list (list consist of head and the rest is list), trees (root + set of child trees), "groups and members" (group is collection of other groups and members).

Comment: What do foreign keys have to do with it? These are classes, not database tables.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - the problem seems to be that the current model is much more table-oriented than object-oriented. These classes are tables.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: right - I was trying to get the OP to say that, and to clarify what he means by keys and foreign keys.

Comment: user### - we will need to know your setup, how are those objects stored? Current question is incomplete.

Comment: Why are fields starting with `_` *public* but properties *private* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such parent/child related classes often have pointer to "parent" to ease navigation up/down through the tree of objects.

I.e.

```
class Student
{
    public Class Parent {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Side note: What you show in the sample look like DTO (data transfer objects) which usually are not exposed beyond innermost layer which talks to database/other storage. Object on other layers would not expose such internal details like DB private keys/ID, but rather useful properties (like `Name`, `Grade`, ...).